# Array initialisation without array size

Tags: arrays, initialization

Can someone please explain how is this array working without the array size?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
int a[]={},i;
for(i=0;i<=3;i++)scanf("%d",&a[i]);
printf("\n\n");
for(i=0;i<=3;i++)printf("%d ",a[i]);
return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C there is no checking for array length at run-time as there is in languages such as Java.  In this code an empty array is created at some location in memory.  When the array is accessed with `a[i]` a memory location is calculated based on the size of the elements (in this case the size of an `int`) and that memory location is accessed, whether you really want it to be accessed or not.  C gives you free reign to do all sorts of things that modern languages do not allow.

On the one hand this allows you to write very efficient code because there is no extra overhead of all the checks but on the other hand it is very easy to write code that crashes in strange ways if you are not fully aware and mindful of how memory allocation works.

One of the big reasons languages such as Java were created was to save the developer from having to worry about these issues as much.  On the one hand, Java is "safer" but on the other hand there is a performance hit.